# find and replace data in multiple records

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a mysql 5 database table with a longtext field that permits html code (via markdown) to be entered as data. Unfortunately, I made a minor copy/paste error that I didn't catch until I had more that 200 records. Because it's the same error on each record

```
href:"http://someurl.com"
```

as opposed to

```
href="http://someurl.com"
```

it would be easier if there were some sql I could write that would allow me to find "href:" on all records and replace with "href=" in the same transaction, than if I have to edit each record individually. Is there anything I can do or am I just screwed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
UPDATE Data_Table 
SET Html_Column = REPLACE(Html_Column, 'href:', 'href=');
```

Comment: sweet. I thought it would be relatively straight forward. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if using phpmyadmin click on sql and run this `UPDATE`Table_Name
 `SET`Column_Name`= replace(Column_Name, 'href:', 'href=')`